# Select historical prices for an exact datetime - MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have a price_list table where I store historical prices for each item.

```
columns are -  id, name, price, start_date, item_id
```

When a price is changed, a one new row is inserted with a current start_date. (Start_date is a datetime format).

Now I need to select prices of all items for an exact datetime. Problem is that this query is slow (1.058 sec):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM price_list h WHERE start_date <= '2013-12-15 12:14:18' ORDER BY start_date DESC) a GROUP BY item_id
```

Very slow is a GROUP BY. Without it it takes 0.075 sec, but each item (item_id) is there a multiple times.

```
bad: SELECT * FROM price_list h WHERE start_date <= '2013-12-15 12:14:18' ORDER BY item_id, start_date DESC
```

Please, can this query be rewritten to be quicker?

Comment: Have you tried SELECT id, name, price, start_date, item_id versus using * ?

Comment: Yes, duration is the same, because I need all columns but I will try LEFT JOIN after group by. Duration goes up when I select name column.

Answer (score -2):

Duration goes to 1 sec when I'm selecting name column. But when I use this query, time is only 0.094 sec:

```
SELECT h.* FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, item_id FROM price_list x WHERE start_date <= '2013-12-15 12:14:18' ORDER BY start_date DESC) a GROUP BY item_id) b LEFT JOIN price_list h ON h.id = b.id
```

Thank you, Ryan!

Comment: -1 for still using `select *` just type in the columns.